# Field labels crispy forms Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I want to use the same model for two forms and change the labels of field how can i change the label?

this is my one form:

```
class jobpostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = jobpost
        fields = ('job_type','title','company_name','location','country','description','start_date','end_date','how_to_apply')

    widgets = {

        'job_type':RadioSelect(),    
        'location':TextInput(attrs={'size':'70','cols': 10, 'rows': 20}),   
        'description': TinyMCE(attrs={'cols':'100', 'row': '80'}),
            'start_date':AdminDateWidget(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}),
            'end_date':AdminDateWidget(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}),
            'how_to_apply':RadioSelect(),

    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(jobpostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'horizontal-form'
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-jobpostform'
        self.helper.form_class = 'blueForms'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'

        self.helper.form_action = '/portal/next/post/'

        self.helper.add_input(Submit(_('submit_addcontent'), 'Preview'))


        super(jobpostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

like i want to change 'location' to 'Job Location'..how can i do this?

Answer (score 21):

This problem is not really specific for Django Crispy Forms.

One option is to set the label in the `init()` method of your [`JobPostForm`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names).

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(JobPostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['location'].label = "Job Location"
```

A good read when dealing with these kind of questions is [Overloading Django Form Fields](http://pydanny.com/overloading-form-fields.html).

Comment: i am doing this but it is not changing label

Comment: How are you displaying the form (fields) in your template?

Comment: displaying the whole form like {% crispy form %}

Comment: For future readers: I had the same problem and I solved it assuring `self.fields['location'].label = "Job Location"` was set **after** `super(JobPostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`. @arie's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

There is an **easier way** to do this. See my example below:

```py
    class CreateAPIKey(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = APIKey
        fields = ["client_id"]
        labels = {
            "client_id": "Nome da Key",
        }
        help_texts = {
            "client_id": _(
                "Um identificador exclusivo de formato livre da chave. 50 caracteres no máximo"
            ),
        }
        widgets = {
            "client_id": forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    "id": "key_id",
                    "required": True,
                    "placeholder": "Entre um nome único para a chave",
                    "label": "dasdasdsdasd",
                }
            ),
        }
```

Then, then rendering the form on the template:

```html
<form class="" method="POST" action="#">
{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 form-group" data-children-count="1">

    {% for field in form %}
       {{ field|as_crispy_field }}
    {% endfor %}
                                                        
  </div>
</form>
```

**RESULT:**

[image: Result of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

In my case calling the `__init__` on my forms.py file worked
CODE FORMAT:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super(ChangeFormNameHere, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['model_filed_default_name'].label = "Your_new_label_name"
```